# Expected speedup from the use of SSSE3 on an Intel machine

Tags: intel, sse

What is the expected speedup from the use of SSSE3 on an Intel machine when implementing an image processing application?

Comment: What application are you talking about? It will speed processes where you perform the same instruction on multiple data but nothing else. So for example it can speed up image processing but not xml parsing.

Comment: to speed up an image processing application

Comment: Speedup relative to what ? Relative to scalar code, or relative to an earlier SSE version ?

Comment: This depends on the exact algorithms used. Without more details the answer doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSSE3 doesn't offer much over SSE3; but it sounds like you're interested in image processing tasks, for which SSSE3 does confer some benefit; if you happen to be doing an operation that maps nicely onto the PMULHRSW instruction (color space transformations, some alpha operations) it can be quite beneficial (2x speedup if you can make heavy use of it; but this will generally require rewriting your code to use it -- it's a very difficult instruction for a compiler to generate for you).

PSHUFB is the other useful instruction; you can use it to do tiny table lookups without needing to do gather loads, which can be exceedingly useful in image processing.  If you have sequences that map naturally to PSHUFB, it can give you huge speedups, but again, making effective use of the instruction can require significant algorithmic changes.

I have never seen really compelling use cases for the other SSSE3 operations (PALIGNR *was* occasionally useful when it was introduced, but since then misaligned memory accesses have gotten significantly more efficient, which makes it much less useful).

Comment: And if I compare the speedup with the scalar code? Still, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I've still found `palignr` to be useful - there's still quite some Core2's out there.

Comment: PSHUFB can be used for basic bitmap processing such as interleaving / deinterleaving of RGB pixels. To see an actual (significant) performance gain, the CPU needs to be of SSE4 architecture - Penryn and up. This is due to the [128-bit Super Shuffle Engine](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/faq-on-45nm-next-generation-intel-coret2-processor-family-penryn-and-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4). In earlier architectures (with SSSE3 but not SSE4), the gain is not significant enough to justify the significant changes required of the algorithm.

Comment: @StephenCanon: The PSHUFB instruction allows some classes of algorithm to be re-implemented in a completely different way, with huge speedup. 4-times speedup is not unheard of. (I do benchmarking for the SIMD code I write.)

Answer (score 1):

If the application consists mainly of `pshufb` or similar instructions, you the application may speedup several times.

If there are some library functions in use, which have an `SSSE3` optimized version, you may see a minimal, barely measurable gain.

If the application does not contain such instructions and the algorithms used do not readily translate into `SSSE3` instructions, the will be no gain at all.

The former case is extremely rare, the latter case extremely likely.