# ARM NEON Saturating Doubling Multiply C/C++ Intrisic for signed 8-bit integers

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon

Why there is no NEON intrisic to perform Signed saturating Rounding Doubling Multiply, like there is for signed 16-bit integers (`vqrdmulhq_s16`) ? More generally, there are only a few intrisics to perform multiplication of 8-bit integers. Is there any particular reason behind the lack of these commands?

Right now, the only solution I can think of, is to split the int8x16 vector, and perform each int8x8 multiplication seperately, by casting int8x8 to int16x8.

Comment: I think [that neon instruction](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vqrdmulhq_s16) is the same operation as [x86 `pmulhrsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhrsw), which also only exists in 16-bit form.  (Although x86 SIMD is notorious for only having some operations in some sizes in general, like only one 8-bit multiply which has horizontal summing of pairs.)

Comment: Anyway, that specific scaling and right-shift with rounding is primarily aimed at speeding up 16-bit audio, and maybe video color-space transformation as mentioned in [Expected speedup from the use of SSSE3 on an Intel machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13232668) /  [Why on earth would I want to use PMULHRSW/VPMULHRSW?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73942946) . Generally yes, if you want to deal with 8-bit integers, sometimes the best option is to unpack to 16-bit and re-pack later.  (e.g. odd/even elements.)

Comment: signed q15 fixed point is the de facto standard in signal processing, hence it deserves some dedicated instructions. There are even some in `aarch32` arm instructions such as `smulw`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I was hopping I would be able to benefit from 16 parallel multiplications. I am trying to accelerate an algorithm. So int16x8 is probably my best option.